# Magento2 - Failed to import products

Tags: magento2, import, csv

We are trying to import products into Magento 2.2.5, but whenever we run the import, we get the following error:

> Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external
>   resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1

The odd thing about this is that there are no images defined in the CSV that we're trying to import. Here's a sample of the CSV:

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,hide_from_product_page,custom_options,base_image
BB-00365,,Default,simple,,base,Wild Daffodil Bulbs (Narcissus obvallaris) - Bulk Buy,"This is a product description>",,,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",24.17,,,,snowdrop-(flore-pleno)-bulbs-(galanthus-nivalis-f.-pleniflorus),"Snowdrop (Flore Pleno) Bulbs (Galanthus nivalis f. pleniflorus) Bulbs For Sale â"" Professional Quality Autumn Garden Flower Bulbs","Snowdrop, Flore, Pleno, Bulbs, Galanthus, nivalis, pleniflorus, bulb, bulbs, flower, autumn, flowering, quality, wholesale, garden, plant, professional, buy, for, sale, mail, order, spring",,14/05/2019 16:31,14/05/2019 16:31,,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=1,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",100000,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,,,,0,"name=Packsize,type=drop_down,required=1,sku=BB-00368-1,title=100 Bulbs,price=24.17,default=0,default_qty=1.0000,price_type=fixed|sku=BB-00368-2,title=1000 Bulbs,price=157.50,default=0,default_qty=1.0000,price_type=fixed|sku=BB-00368-3,title=250 Bulbs,price=30.00,default=0,default_qty=1.0000,price_type=fixed|sku=BB-00368-4,title=50 Bulbs,price=-7.50,default=0,default_qty=1.0000,price_type=fixed",
```

As you can see, the `base_image` column is empty, and I don't understand why Magento is generating this error. We have already tried to import images using this format, and received the error, but I thought that removing the images would at least allow us to import products, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Has anyone encountered this problem and know a possible fix so that we can import our products into 2.2.5?

I have already tried the solutions on StackExchange and the official Magento forum (including the hotfix listed), but none of them have worked.

Comment: If you don't want to import image why you have base_image column?

Just remove it and try again

Comment: Removing the column produces the same error...

Comment: give me csv  will upload in my code and check

Comment: @RutveeSojitra https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HzeJSKfWltxo5vL3maazrRz5V8ozTod6

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but this will work I think

Add Null to your base_image fields and try once.

Comment: This produces exactly the same error: *1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1*